# What is an example of a Weak Limit that is not Limit

Tags: category-theory

I was wondering if there was a standard example of weak limit that is not a limit (in the categorical sense). I have been thinking of the problem, and it seems like weak limits are  limits most of the time, so I was wondering if a simple example exists.

Any examples are greatly enjoyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In algebraic topology a cofibered pair $(X,A)$ is often defined by means of a *weak* pushout:

$\begin{array}{ccc}
A\times\left\{ 0\right\}  & \rightarrow & X\times\left\{ 0\right\} \\
\downarrow &  & \downarrow\\
A\times\mathbb{I} & \rightarrow & X\times\mathbb{I}\end{array}$

Looking at *weak* limits as objects of a category you end up with the limits as terminal objects. Dually looking at *weak* colimits as objects you end up with the colimits as initial objects.

Comment: @chanler. You accepted, but to my regrets I made a mistake in saying that weak products in posets are lower bounds (also the dual of it -concerning coproducts - is wrong). I was not really comparing *limit* and *weak limit*, but  *cones* and *limiting cones* there. In a poset arrows in a homset are *automatically* unique so there cannot be any  distinction between *limit* and *weak limit* there. In an edit I took away the mistake. If you withdraw your acceptance then I have full understanding for that. My apologies.

Answer (score 5):

Have to admit I had no idea previously about *weak* limits, but thanks to nLab [weak limits](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/weak+limit), maybe we will be able to understand the following example: every *non-empty* (aka *inhabited*) set is a weak limit (namely, a *weak* final object) in the category of sets. But only sets with just one element are final objects; that is, *true* limits.

Why? Because, given any non-empty set $S$, there is always a map $f: A \longrightarrow S$ from any other set $A$ (pick any element $s\in S$ and send all elements in $A$ to $s$, for instance). But the map $f$ is *unique* only when $S$ has just one element, obviously.

(Ha! They're funny those weak limits.  :-D   )